# How to fail CI script in case of command error when using forfiles?

Tags: windows, batch-file, appveyor

I've the following `appveyor.yml` file:

```
test_script:
- forfiles /m *.mqh /c "mql /s @path"
build: off
platform: x86
```

which aims to check the syntax (`/s`) of all source code files found in the current directory.

However despite of compiler errors, the final result is reported as: *Build success*.

How do I fail the test script by using above approach?

---

I'm looking something similar to `set -e` on Linux. The compiler returns 1 error on exit as expected, as it works fine when using with `wine` on Linux. But the whole build script doesn't fail as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppVeyor happy because whole command return code is 0. I think it's return code is 0 because last iteration was happy. I am not sure how to make it return error in case it least one iteration failed with `forfiles`, but with PowerShell this should work:

`test_script:
- ps: $mqlScriptSuccess = $true
- ps: Get-ChildItem  | ForEach-Object {if ($_.Name.EndsWith(".mqh")){.\mql /s /mql$env:ver $_.FullName; if(!$?){$mqlScriptSuccess = $?; Write-Warning "mlq error"}}}
- ps: if (!$mqlScriptSuccess) {throw "At least one mql test failed"}`

Note that you can also change `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to get deeper coverage.